# Moving average that resets based on another binary column

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing blood percentage (hemoglobin level) and I am interested in calculating a backwards-looking (ie. not centred) moving average that restarts everytime the patient goes below 7 in hemoglobin level.

`Pt_id` represents the patient id, `hemoglobin_level` is the given hemoglobin, and `anemia_start` is the column that indicates when a given patients hemoglobin first goes below 7 (ie. when `anemia_start`  equals 1).

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(pt_id = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                hemoglobin_level = c(8,6,5,8,7),
                anemia_start = c(0,1,0,0,0))

df
  pt_id hemoglobin_level anemia_start
1     1                8            0
2     1                6            1
3     1                5            0
4     1                8            0
5     1                7            0
```

Expected output column is:

```
moving_average = c(8, 6, 5.5, 6.3, 6.5)
```

The moving average is restarted once anemia starts, so the second value is 6 and then the moving average continues.

I know how to create a moving average (using zoo package / slider), but i do not know how to make it restart conditionally based on the "anemia_start column".

Thanks for any help.

##### Further information:

My professor did this in SAS using a bunch of if statements, but I have had a hard time translating it to R.

In order to understand the expected output, here's a picture of my professor's output (made in SAS) that I would like to reproduce in R. The column I'm having a hard time reproducing is the one called `hb_gennemsnit` (= Hemoglobin average).

[image]

he has created a bunch of intermediary columns in SAS to produce his code. Its in danish but HB = hemoglobin (the one I called hemoglobin level)
`ptnr slut` = patient number end, `ptnr start` = patient number start, and `HB gennemsnit` = hemoglobin average.

The `hb_gennemsnit` column is the moving average column that I am trying to reproduce in R

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: And what kind of moving average? Centred? Trailing? How many periods? Over the whole period? Expected output would help a lot.

Comment: Are you sure that is your expected output? Your edited input is length 5, but the output is length 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` and `slider`:

```
library(data.table)
library(slider)

setDT(df)

# Helper function
adder <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {

    if (x[i] == 0L) {
      if (i != 1L) {
        x[i] <- x[i-1]
      } else {x[i] <- 1}
    } else {
      x[i] <- x[i-1] + 1
    }
  }

  return(x)
}

# Create period index
df[, period := adder(anemia_start), by = pt_id]

# Do moving average
df[, moving_average := slide_vec(
  .x = hemoglobin_level
  .f = mean,
  .before = Inf),
  by = c("pt_id", "period")]
```

Output:

```
df
    pt_id hemoglobin_level anemia_start period moving_average
 1:     1                8            0      1       8.000000
 2:     1                6            1      2       6.000000
 3:     1                5            0      2       5.500000
 4:     1                8            0      2       6.333333
 5:     1                7            0      2       6.500000
 6:     2                8            0      1       8.000000
 7:     2                4            1      2       4.000000
 8:     2                3            0      2       3.500000
 9:     2                9            0      2       5.333333
10:     2                9            0      2       6.250000
```

OP edited the question so that there is a unique value for `pt_id`. In this case, you *can* just drop the `by = pt_id` everywhere, but the original solution will still work.